# Problema com .show()

Tags: jquery

Basicamente eu tenho um código jQuery que deveria de mostrar os widgets numa certa da página do meu website (a propriedade deles seria #left,#right) só que não está funcionando e eu não consigo perceber o porquê. Eis o código que estou utilizando:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(location.pathname=='/forum'){
        jQuery('#left,#right').show()
    }
});
```

Eu uso para mostrar os widgets somente no página e para oculta-los das outras páginas eu uso este CSS:

```
#left,#right{display:none}
```

Alguém poderia ver o que está errado? Agradecido desde já.

Comment: O que esta retornando no location.pathname quando você acessa a página forum?

Comment: Única coisa que está retornando é isto: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
VM93:1 'webkitIDBObjectStore' is deprecated. Please use 'IDBObjectStore' instead.

Comment: Aparentemente o erro não esta no seu trecho de código, talvez alguma outra função esta dando erro.

Comment: Fábio, você sabe debugar pelo console do navegador? Se existem erros no console eles podem estar impedindo seu código de rodar. Procure sempre identar o seu código, facilita para encontrar possiveis erros. Outra dica caso você não saiba debugar pelo console é colocar um alert("") antes da função "jQuery().show()", para se certificar que você está entrando dentro do if.

Comment: Existem dois erros como mencionei acima:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
VM93:1 'webkitIDBObjectStore' is deprecated. Please use 'IDBObjectStore' instead.

Comment: Esses erros as vezes são em outro arquivo js e passam batido. O ideal é que você debugue o seu código.

Comment: Fábio, esse `Uncaught SyntaxError` desapareceu?

Comment: Sim Sérgio! :D Bem estranho.

Comment: Fabio: e ele retorna se tirares window de window.location.pathname?

Comment: Sim, por isso que acho bem estranho.

Comment: Realmente isso não faz sentido. `location` é uma variável global, pode ser acessada com ou sem `window.`. A não ser que haja uma outra, local, com o mesmo nome e no escopo em que você está.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque `location.pathname` por `window.location.pathname` no seu código.

Comment: Funcionou! ^^ Estranho, só por causa do window.location.pathname lol

Comment: Dei um edit na resposta, podes [edit] e juntar mais uma linha a explicar se quiseres. Acho contudo que o problema na verdade não era este :P

Comment: Zanotta, para tirar dúvidas sobre a pergunta, por favor use os comentários. Sem problemas porque a edição do sensei Sergio cravou na mosca... :)